# Decrementation in an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray, warnings

I'm implementing an application in which i use a 'NSMutableArray'. I add some objects into.
But I've found a warning in my 'memory management'. In fact, I did :

```
for (int s = 0; s < aNumber ; s++)
{
    [[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:s] release];
}
```

But it gives me :

"Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"

After some researches, I found some things like add :

```
myObject = nil;
```

But here, when i do :

```
for (int s = 0; s < aNumber; s++)
{
    [[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:s] release];
    [ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:s] = nil;
}
```

it gives me another 'warning' :

"Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an objective-c message not allowed"

How could i fix this sort of situation please ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why are you trying to release these objects? Do you just want to remove them from the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error you are getting because you are trying to release the object that is owned by the array. NSMutableArray objects are read only and cannot simply be assigned, that is why you are getting the second error. For inserting objects into the array use `addObject:`.

What you want to do is call `[ArrayOfViews removeAllObjects]`.

Comment: And the second error too - removing all objects as you say is the correct way to handle both.

Comment: Actually he gets the second error because he tries to assign something to a readonly return. `[array objectAtIndex:0] = @"Some String";` This would have been an error as well. It's right, that you aren't allowed to hold nil values in an array but that isn't the reason he's getting that specific error here.

Comment: So all i have to do when i want to delete the array is doing [ArrayOfViews removeAllObjects] ?